# Can we play speex file from java?

Tags: java, jspeex

Is it possible to play a speex file from java. I have encoded a wav file to speex file and i can even decode it back to wave file again and play the audio. But i dont want to decode and play the file throught java. Are there any alternatives to play the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSpeex](http://jspeex.sourceforge.net/)

> JSpeex is a Java port of the Speex speech codec (Open Source/Free Software patent-free audio compression format designed for speech). It provides both the decoder and the encoder in pure Java, as well as a JavaSound SPI.
>
> The current version of the JSpeex library is 0.9.2 and it is based on the code from Speex 1.0.3.
>
> As well as the JSpeex library, **there is also JavaSound player that uses the library to play any Speex encoded audio file.** The player is a modified version of the jlGui player by JavaZOOM.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will take a look into the player.

Comment: Sure, but don't forget to mark this as an answer as soon as you prove this is an answer :)

Comment: Definietly when my spx file plays.

Comment: Folks, JSpeex looks like a dead-end project. I have not seen any activity in its mailing lists or help forums in quite some time. I would steer clear of it and use some other alternative.

Comment: @Raj: what other alternatives are there?